# Factoring unit vectors forces me to find specific solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is a very trivial matter, however given I have the vector field

$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} = e^t \hat k$

Integrating 2 ways:

don't factor $\hat k$:

$\vec{v} = \int e^t \hat k dt$

I would assume doing this way would be

$\vec{v} = e^t \hat k + \vec{c}(x,y,z)$

But Factoring $\hat k$:

$\vec{v} = \hat k \int e^t dt$

$\vec{v} = \hat k ( e^t + c(x,y,z))$

$\vec{v} = e^t \hat k + c(x,y,z) \hat k$

Which method is correct? Or are they both correct, yet way 2 forces it to be a specific solution to this differential equation.

Doing it 2 ways makes the vector constant have different directions? Ie, way 2, forces it to have only a k component.

Comment: Integrate $\vec{v}' = (0, 0, e^{t})$ componentwise. What do you find? How does it match up with the two results you wrote down?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the first method is correct. And the second method is incorrect because , as you pointed out, there is an 0i+0j component. So Factoring the unit vector makes no sense, since under the integral, I would have i/k j/k, unless split up